# help with simplifying a boolean expression

Tags: logic

Can someone please explain this to me? I do not understand how the zy term is eliminated:

$xz + x'y + zy = xz + x'y$

What is the algebraic step in between?

Comment: What have *you* tried on your own behalf?  Where else do you see $z$ appear?  Where else do you see $y$ appear?  and keep in mind, there may be more than one "algebraic step" in between.

Comment: well that's the thing. I am learning boolean algebra in class and we have been taught some identities. Based on what I've learned so far, there wasn't anything immediately obvious to me that I could apply to this expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of the **Consensus Theorem**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem

To show it using more basic principles:

$xz + x'y + zy$ = (Adjacency)

$xyz + xy'z + x'yz + x'yz' + xzy + x'zy$ = (Idempotence  ($xyz = xzy$ and $x'yz = x'zy$)

$xyz + xy'z + x'yz + x'yz'$ = (Adjacency)

$xz + x'y$

Alternatively:

$xz + x'y + zy$ = (Adjacency)

$xz + x'y + zyx + zyx'$ = (Absorption ($xz$ absorbs $zyx$ and $x'y$ absorbs $zyx'$))

$xz + x'y$

I used:

**Adjacency**

$x = xy + xy'$

**Idempotence**

$x = x + x$

**Absorption**

$x = x + xy$

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer.